# DJANGO : Hit an api multiple times simultaneously

Tags: django, multithreading, parallel-processing

Here is my project situation. I am using Django

I am running a cron job every day at a particular time. What I do is I query a list of users whose payment needs to be requested. The payment api is collection of two api's each per user depending on the type of subscription.

Question :: how should the api be hit. 
1. Should be hit in order(i.e. one after the other. I think this is not a good way) 
2. Should I hit it concurrently (all api hits are independent of each other).

If the second way is better, what are the tools/libraries in django that I can use.

Definitely the second way will be much faster since it is involving parallelism. But will it put a lot of pressure/load on the server. What is the standard way to go in such a scenario?

Comment: your options are async/await , threading, celery workers

Comment: implement sequential and if you have a performance problem, come back to this. As you also commented hitting in parallel puts a extra thread to work in the server. If you do not need the extra speed why load the server?